# On Scroll Fixed Element Moving From Initial Point

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/19451/

I am building a website using Bootstrap 3. On scroll I have an image that sticks to the page by changing position to fixed. This works however it always shiftss a bit out of place once it turns fixed. I am aware this has something to do with the margins (and I have played with pixels and this seems to practically solve the problem, the margin-left needs to be a % for the responsive website). When it turns to fixed I don't want the image to shift around from it's initial resting place

Here's the code:

HTML

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-5">
                <h2 class="white">Some Text</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-7">
                <img class="img-responsive screen-phone" src="img/phone.png">
            </div>
</div><!--END ROW-->
```

CSS

```
.screen-phone{
    max-width:300px;
    margin-top:25px;
    margin-left:25%;
    z-index:999;

}
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop()>1120){
        $('.screen-phone').css('position','fixed').css('top','0');
    }else{$('.screen-phone').css('position','static');
    };
 });
});
```

Comment: Hello, the problem comes certainly form this value : "1120" in your javascript code. Try to increase or decrease this value to remove the "shift" effect.

Comment: Why would this value matter? It is just the moment in which the position is triggered. In the fiddle I've changed it because it happens earlier on. This fixed event is supposed to occur at the specified scrollTop value

Answer (score 0):

bootstrap doesn't like it very much when you screw around with it's margins. It has gutter system and your margins are pretty crazy:P

If you delete those margin declarations, everything works as you want it to, no?

Comment: True, this doesn't shift anymore. Same if I put the margin-left in pixels such as margin-left:250px. Is there no way to have it stick in a responsive format?

Comment: So you wanted responsive margin? I didn't know that. But the bootstrap columns themselves are responsive. So you could use offset on the image column. So instead of `<div class="col-sm-7">` you would have `<div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-2">` try it like that. Your new solution may work but I don't think it's the right approach.

Comment: Nope, this causes it to shove off to the right when it turns to fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I figured this out. What needs to be done is you put a separate class on the containing DIV. You give it left:(whatever your percent value is here). You take margin-left OFF the containing image. If using Bootstrap like me, you'll have to get around margin issues you can create two classes like I did to remove the margin of the row and col-sm-7. In my case I did:

```
.screen-phone{
 max-width:300px;
 margin-top:25px;
 /*Removed margin-left:25%*/
 z-index:999;

}

.sticker{
 left:25%
}

.zero-row{
 margin:0;
}

.no-margin{
 width:0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row zero-row">
        <div class="col-sm-5">
            <h2 class="white">Some Text</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-7 no-margin sticker">
            <img class="img-responsive screen-phone" src="img/phone.png">
        </div>
</div><!--END ROW-->
```

Updated Fidde: https://jsfiddle.net/1chkghhq/1/